# Structure other than a wall to reduce wind?

Tags: structural-engineering, retaining-wall

I own a small farm which apparently lands in the middle of 2 small mountains therefore is a big wind tunnel.  The wind gets pretty insane here.  Wondering if there is a structure I can put around my yard that would reduce the wind but be more cost effective than building a 10ft brick wall around my entire property.

Answer (score 5):

If you think about fast growing trees, you'll get a wind break that isn't particularly expensive or labor intensive. Farmers in the center of the continent of the USA historically used this method to reduce the amount of topsoil lost to such things.

[HobbyFarms](https://www.hobbyfarms.com/5-great-trees-to-use-for-windbreaks/) recommends Eastern Red or Northern White cedar for windbreaks, although the former is a shorter breed, while the latter can reach one hundred feet, somewhat outside your desired range.

[image: windbreak image]

If vegetation isn't in your future, mimicking a stand of trees may provide similar results. Pole-type structures with "branches and leaves" will break up the force of wind.